# Reading values from dynamically created TextBox ASP.NET (Within table)

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, dynamically-generated

So I have a `List<SettingsValue>`, which I'll to use to populate a `<table runat="server">` (`System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable`).

**The problem is that when the form is submitted the fields are recreated with the initial values. And then when I loop through the elements none of them has been changed. But if I don't recreate them then the code that checks the input values doesn't even find the controls.**

*I don't want to post the data via query string*

I receive the settings by calling a method `GetSettingsFromDatabase` which takes an parameter 'id'. Id is a key for an 'application' that has settings. On the page there is an combo box where the user selects for which application they wish to change the settings for. When an item is selected in the combo box a post back occurs and then I wish to make another call to LoadSettings().

#### HTML - Row:

```
<tr align="left" valign="top" runat="server">
    <th runat="server">
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="{field.Name}" />
    </th>
    <td runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt{field.ID}_{field.Name}" runat="server" Text="{value}" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

#### C# - Models:

```
public class SettingsValue
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long FieldID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string RelatedID { get; set; }

    public SettingsField Field { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsField
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }

    public SettingsCategory Category { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsCategory
{
    public SettingsCategory()
    {
        Fields = new List<SettingsField>();
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public SettingsCategoryType Type { get; set; }

    public List<SettingsField> Fields { get; private set; }
}
```

#### C# - Row generation:

```
private void LoadSettings(long id)
{
    // The id represents some application that has settings

    List<SettingsValue> setting = new List<SettingsValue>();
    if (id > 0)
        settings = GetSettingsFromDatabase(id);

    RenderSettings(settings);
}

private void RenderSettings(List<SettingsValue> settings)
{
    table.Rows.Clear();

    foreach (var value in settings)
    {
        var field = value.Field;
        var fieldGUI_ID = string.Format("{0}_{1}", field.ID, field.Name);

        var row = new HtmlTableRow();
        row.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        row.Align = "left";
        row.VAlign = "top";

        var th = new HtmlTableCell("th");
        th.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

        var td = new HtmlTableCell("td");
        td.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

        var input = new TextBox();
        input.ID = "txt" + fieldGUI_ID;
        input.Text = value.Value;
        input.Width = new Unit("305px");
        input.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

        var label = new Label();
        label.Text = field.Name;
        label.Attributes.Add("for", input.ClientID);


        th.Controls.Add(label);
        row.Cells.Add(th);

        td.Controls.Add(input);
        row.Cells.Add(td);

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

#### C# - Page load

```
protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack )
    {
        LoadSettings(-1);
    }
}
```

#### C# - On submit

We are using the ComponentArt library for callbacks `<ComponentArt:Callback ID="callSettings" runat="server" OnCallback="callSettings_OnCallback" />`, but it's not that different from regular ASP.NET.

```
protected void callSettings_OnCallback( object sender, ComponentArt.Web.UI.CallBackEventArgs e )
{
    long id = 421;
    List<SettingsValue> settings = GetSettingsFromDatabase(id);

    List<SettingsValue> updatedValues = new List<SettingsValue>();
    foreach (SettingsField f in fields)
    {
        var val = GetSettingValueFromInput(f);
        if (val != null)
            updatedValues.Add(val);
    }

    UpdateSettingsToDatabase(updatedValues);
}

private SettingsValue GetSettingValueFromInput(SettingsField field)
{
    var fieldGUI_ID = "txt" + string.Format("{0}_{1}", field.ID, field.Name);
    var res = settings.Single(x => x.FieldID == field.ID);

    foreach (HtmlTableRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (HtmlTableCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            var ctrl = cell.FindControl(fieldGUI_ID);
            var input = ctrl as TextBox;
            if (ctrl == null || input == null)
                continue;

            res.Value = input.Text;
            return res;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

I have looked on several other questions but have not gotten it to work.

Comment: Why don't you store it in the `Session` instead of posting all to the client via `ViewState`? Or even better, use a `GridView` or other databound webcontrol that is rendered as table which stores changeable informations in `ViewState` automatically?

Comment: I cannot change any layout or major changes to the page

Comment: @TimSchmelter What should I store in `Session`?

Comment: @LazyTarget Your question is very similar to may question, can you please read [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830416/dynamic-settings-page-for-application) and post your idea there?

Comment: Maybe [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i) would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating controls dynamically so you must initialize the value first time only. Something like this,

```
PageLoad() {
    var txtBox = new TextBox();
    this.Controls.Add(txtBox);
    if (!this.IsPostBack) {
        txtBox.Text = "this is initial value";
    }
}
```

Now as you can see the initial value will only be set when page is first time loaded (without postback). Next time when page is posted back, the control will recreate and the value will be set automatically by the page.

For Dynamic Controls, you must create and add controls each time when page is loaded (whether Postback or Non-Postback). But you don't have to set the initial value each time. You set the initial value only when Page is first time loaded.